# PHP Input Validation and Handling MySQL Errors: What's The Safest Route?

Tags: php, mysql, validation, error-handling

When it comes to SQL injections (blind or otherwise), it seems the best method for prevention is to use prepared statements combined with input/output validation/escaping, but I would like to know the best practice when input validation fails or to handle MySQL errors (failed queries) in order to discourage injections even further and bolster security as much as possible?

For example, when validating $_GET input: I'm expecting numeric input, what is the best practice in a situation like this:

```
if (is_numeric($_GET['id']))
{
    // Run queries and continue with page output as normal
}
else
{
    // Input is not what's expected so the query is guaranteed to fail...
    // What is the best thing to do here?
}
```

Is it best to A.) kill the script with die() resulting in a blank page...B.) redirect to another page (i.e index)...C.) output a generic error (i.e. "no results found")...D.) something else?

What about when a query fails that is dependent upon $_GET input which is defined by the script and not user input? (meaning it can only fail if the URL is tampered with)...is it best to output a generic error or just kill the script since average visitors won't be messing with the URL?

Comment: that approach really depends on you and your application. But I think showing error is better so that you know the query has failed.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a parsing. Run the query with value:`(int)$_GET['id']`
If you don't want your query to fail if that result is null, you can replace WHERE id=(int)$_GET['id'] into `WHERE id IN ('(int)$_GET['id']')`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to handle the error from mysql opr php than you can use try and cache which is the best practice and you can display any message in Cache block...

i hope this one is help to you.